# Помогите укоротить (упростить) код, и возможно ли это сделать?

Tags: python

Только начат учиться.
Орфографические ошибки не интересны, сам знаю что есть.
Можно ли укоротить или упростить код?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы могли бы привести код не в виде скриншота, а обычным текстом?

Comment: код надо предоставить в текстовом виде, чтобы при желании помочь, его можно было скопировать в ide, в таком виде никто вам не поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и быть, я переписал ваш код с исправлением ошибок (бонус!). Вот что из этого вышло:

```
available_pizza = ["Pepperoni", "Salami", "Margarita", "AlL Fungi", "Capricious", "Hawaii"]
available_topping = ["Double cheese", "BBQ", "Spinet", "Champions", "Tomato", "Brie"]
print("We have " + ", ".join(available_pizza))
print("And you can add some topping in your Pizza")
print("\n".join(available_pizza))
chose_pizza = ["Pepperoni", "Margarita", "Hawaii", "Quarto Cheese"]
chose_topping = ["Double cheese", "Tomato", "Cheddar"]
print(f"You have chosen {', '.join(chose_pizza)}. With {', '.join(chose_topping)}")
for topping in chose_topping:
    if topping not in available_topping:
        print(f"I am Sorry we don't have {topping}")
for pizza in chose_pizza:
    if pizza not in available_pizza:
        print(f"I am sorry we don't have {pizza}")
    else:
        print("You can finish you order Now")
```

Я не силён в питоне, так что наверняка можно ещё как то упростить (циклы, допустим)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ